# How do I view multiple api's in Django REST api?

Tags: django, rest

So I have two models, and I'm trying to get both models in my api view. So here's the code:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def mainPage(request, pk):
    thisQuestion = Question.objects.filter(question_number=pk)
    thisAnswer = Answer.objects.filter(authuser_id=request.user.id, question_number=pk)
    
    questionSerialized = QuestionSerializer(thisQuestion, many=True)
    answerSerialized = AnswerSerializer(thisAnswer, many=True)

    return Response(answerSerialized.data, questionSerialized.data)
```

Obviously, the problem is in the return part. How do I get both in this case?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a dictionary in the `Response` as followings:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def mainPage(request, pk):
    thisQuestion = Question.objects.filter(question_number=pk)
    thisAnswer = Answer.objects.filter(authuser_id=request.user.id, question_number=pk)
    
    questionSerialized = QuestionSerializer(thisQuestion, many=True)
    answerSerialized = AnswerSerializer(thisAnswer, many=True)

    return Response({"answers":answerSerialized.data, "questions": questionSerialized.data})
```

---

**Update**

I suppose you want to get 1 item per type. To do this, you can use `get()` instead of `filter()` to get the specific item and remove `many=True` to serialize the specific item.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def mainPage(request, pk):
    thisQuestion = Question.objects.get(question_number=pk)
    thisAnswer = Answer.objects.get(authuser_id=request.user.id, question_number=pk)
    
    questionSerialized = QuestionSerializer(thisQuestion)
    answerSerialized = AnswerSerializer(thisAnswer)

    return Response({"answer":answerSerialized.data, "question": questionSerialized.data})
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it worked for you. Btw, I updated the answer to add another option. Please have a look at it.